# Java Append( ) method : String vs. StringBuilder

Tags: java

When appending the subset of a String to a String object, the last position in the number of characters specified by the append statement is NOT included as part of the return object. However, when appending the subset of an char Array to a char Array object, the last position in the number of characters specified by the append statement is included as part of the return object. Why is this?

Example -

```
class  String {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String name = "Java7";
        sb.append(name, 1,3);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
/* result is:

 av
 */

class  char {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] name = {'J', 'A', 'V', 'A', '7'};
        sb.append(name, 1,3);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
/* result is:

AVA
*/
```

Comment: Because a `char` array has nothing to do with a `String` and the [Javadoc for StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(char[],%20int,%20int)) is pretty clear on what each of those *different* append methods does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when char[]
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(char[]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%5b%5d), int, int)

Appends the string representation of a subarray of the char array argument to this sequence.
Characters of the char array str, starting at index offset, are appended, in order, to the contents of this sequence. The length of this sequence increases by the value of len.

The overall effect is exactly as if the arguments were converted to a string by the method String.valueOf(char[],int,int), and the characters of that string were then appended to this character sequence.

Parameters:
str - the characters to be appended.
offset - the index of the first char to append.
len - the number of chars to append.

when String
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence), int, int)

Appends a subsequence of the specified CharSequence to this sequence.
Characters of the argument s, starting at index start, are appended, in order, to the contents of this sequence up to the (exclusive) index end. The length of this sequence is increased by the value of end - start.

Let n be the length of this character sequence just prior to execution of the append method. Then the character at index k in this character sequence becomes equal to the character at index k in this sequence, if k is less than n; otherwise, it is equal to the character at index k+start-n in the argument s.

If s is null, then this method appends characters as if the s parameter was a sequence containing the four characters "null".

Parameters:
s - the sequence to append.
start - the starting index of the subsequence to be appended.
end - the end index of the subsequence to be appended.
Returns:
a reference to this object.

So when you append char[] using sb.append(name, 1,3); means start from index 1, and need a 3 characters.

and String sb.append(name, 1,3); means start from index 1 and stop at index 3, but not including 3, which is a (3-1)=2 long string

Answer (score 0):

The methods are different. The 3rd argument in [the one that accepts a `char[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) is the length, ie the number of characters to append.

> Characters of the char array `str`, starting at `index` offset, are
>   appended, in order, to the contents of this sequence. The length of
>   this sequence increases by the value of `len`.

[The one that accepts a `CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int%29) (a `String` in your example) says

> Characters of the argument `s`, starting at index `start`, are appended,
>   in order, to the contents of this sequence **up to the (exclusive) index
>   `end`.**